# fuse: invalid argument, MacOS

Tags: sshfs

I've been mounting a Linux filesystem on my Mac successfully with the following syntax:

```
sshfs -o allow_other, defer_permissions username@remotelinux:/ ~/mnt/mountpoint
```

Starting yesterday, this fails with

```
fuse: invalid argument '/Users/macusername/mnt/mountpoint'
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29885911/619754) suggestion, but it hasn't helped, although I'm not 100% sure I'm pointing to the correct rsa file.  But note that this failure just started.  I've rebooted both computers: same failure.

The mount point appears to exist.  If I try to unmount it, I'm told that it is not mounted.

Any hints on solutions or debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing "allow_other" fixed this.  Here's what works:

```
sshfs -o defer_permissions username@remotelinux:/ ~/mnt/mountpoint
```

Sometimes the connection is lost, and when re-established this statement does not work.  The mount point is left in some kind of limbo.  In such cases unmount the file system

```
umount ~/mnt/mountpoint
```